# Google reCAPTCHA 2 com AJAX

Tags: ajax, recaptcha

Estou utilizando o [*reCAPTCHA*](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) com AJAX.

Quando a pagina é carregada a validação do *reCAPTCHA* funciona normalmente, mas quando da erro no formulário e a pagina não foi carregada o *reCAPTCHA* devolve um erro e a sessão expira.

Como fazer o *reCAPTCHA* funcionar com AJAX sem *reload*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema.

Utilizei o  `grecaptcha.reset()`.

Comment: Quando for possível, marque a resposta como aceita clicando sobre a marca ✔ abaixo da pontuação.